# UIImage sort on UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimage

I am almost getting there with what I want. Lasts parts are the hardest one. So basically my last view is a view where max 6 UIImages can get onto. and sort over the screen so they have the same ratio:

**Example:**
View:

```
-------
  UI
  UI
-------
```

So this would be 2 UIImages at the same ratio in the center of the screen.

**Example 2**
View:

```
-------
UI  UI
  UI
-------
```

This would be 3 UIImages on my view.

I could hardcode this, by doing a very long If/else statement I think and lot's of views in the storyboard. But I would like a solution for doing this on a right way.

How do I need to solve this?

Regards!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a dynamic layout of the images depending on their size? Try a collection view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this: (untested, to give you an idea)

```
NSInteger itemInRow = 2;
NSInteger itemsCount = 6;  // Assume 6
NSInteger imageViewWidth = myImageView.frame.size.width;
NSInteger imageViewHeight = myImageView.frame.size.height;
NSInteger leftMargin = (imageViewWidth * itemInRow) / 2;

for(int i = 1; i <= itemsCount / itemInRow; i++)
{
    myImageView.center = CGPointMake((imageViewWidth + leftMargin) * i, imageViewHeight * i);
}
```